# Why is rice farming more difficult?

Tags: food-crops

In the link below, it is mentionned that the agriculture of rice needs more qualifications than agriculture in other civilisations, I imagine like the wheat or corn.

https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/951/why-and-when-did-agriculture-lose-its-prestige?rq=1

Do you have any explanation on that? I never tried to grow wheat or rice so any basic explanation is interested.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what you mean by "qualifications" but growing rice efficiently does need technology to control the water level in the rice paddies, and if you want to grow rice in a hilly region, you need to terrace the landscape to contain the standing water required.

On the other hand growing wheat and corn was pretty much a matter of "sow the seed and wait till harvest time," in early agriculture. Of course you needed to know *when* to plant (for which astronomy was useful!) but once discovered, using that knowledge didn't require any "technology" beyond naked-eye observations of the stars.

Technology does enter into cereal growing to convert the grain into flour, once laborious hand-milling by individual families is replaced by wind or water mills, which were the "high tech engineering" of their day. But operating and constructing mills were a specialist occupations separate from "farming," and unlike farming were not labour-intensive, in the sense that one miller could process the output of hundreds of farm workers.

Comment: Note: also growing rice is simple on plain region. Because of TV (?) we are used to think about rice in hill regions, and not in the more frequent boring plains.